# git svn command to get remote HEAD revision number

Tags: git-svn

is there a `git svn` command that will tell me the HEAD revision on the svn **remote** repositiory *before* I perform a `git svn fetch`?

---

**Use case** (Since someone asked why I'd want to do this.)

I want to check if there has been a large number of commits to the remote repository before I start the fetch, so I know whether to do something else* before it finishes, or just sit staring at the console because it will be done quickly.

* something else = go and make a coffee

Comment: Probably not, curious why would you need one?

Comment: @MykolaGurov so I can estimate how long the rebase will take

Comment: @SamHasler, You can check this file `.git\refs\remotes\<YourRemote>`. The last line shows HEAD of your svn remote.

Comment: @SamHasler, If my last comment is not suitable you could look into this file `.git\info\refs` look for your svn remote in this and get its `SHA-1` value. But you will have to map it to svn's rev and this will be your HEAD that you are looking for.

Comment: @SamHasler, Or simply you can read the file which with your remote name under `.git\svn\refs\remotes` directory. The last `+rXXX` will be the HEAD of the remote.

Comment: @JaiminAjmeri how is that up-to-date with the remote repository *before* i do `git dvn fetch`. i.e. I want to know what the HEAD revision is on the actual remote repository; not the last one my repo has from that repository.

Comment: @SamHasler, git doesn't support this as per my experience. You will to use svn.exe for that.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a similar feature with [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html).

[`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) itself might, through [`git svn info <url>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-eminfoem), which does an [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/fr/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) (without `-r/-revision` option support though)
Try using it with the URL of the remote SVN repository.
If it does now work, try `svn info <url>` directly.